# Flatten Binary Tree to Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, binary-tree

Given a binary tree, flatten it to a linked list in-place.

For example, given the following tree:

```
    1
   / \
  2   5
 / \   \
3   4   6
```

The flattened tree should look like:

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
     \
      4
       \
        5
         \
          6
```

I'm of the other solutions out there but I want to ask why is it when I run my code, the output just matches the input tree.

```
public void flatten(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null)
            return;
        TreeNode newRoot = new TreeNode(root.val);
        List<TreeNode> list = new ArrayList<>();

        helper(root,list);
        TreeNode current = newRoot;
        for(int i = 1; i < list.size();i++) {
            current.right = new TreeNode(list.get(i).val);
            current = current.right;
        }
        root = newRoot;
    }

    public void helper(TreeNode oldNode,List<TreeNode> list) {
        if(oldNode != null) {
            list.add(oldNode);
            helper(oldNode.left,list);
            helper(oldNode.right,list);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want the experts to find your question, add the corresponding tags ... please read [ask].

Comment: Or just change the function to return a `TreeNode` and `return newRoot`;

Answer (score 0):

When you reassign references passed to the methods as arguments it doesn't have any effect outside of that method. So your last assignment `root = newRoot;` doesn't make any effect outside of your `flatten()` method. You need to change links of `root` object instead if creating another node.

```
TreeNode root = new TreeNode(10);
flatten(root);
```

after call to `flatten` `root` will point to exactly same object as before call. 
You can try to do the following instead of `root = newRoot;`

```
root.right = newRoot.right;
root.left = newRoot.left;
```